# Multiple File Input Fields in One Form Jquery upload, not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I'm trying to implement (without success) a multi file input in a single form with jQuery-File-Upload. The plugin seems to support this behaviour:

[Multiple File Input Fields in One Form](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Input-Fields-in-One-Form)

I cannot make it work. What's the related javascript to make it work? This is the form in the partial example:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="php/index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span16 fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="progressbar fileupload-progressbar"><div style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            <span class="btn success fileinput-button">
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <!-- Extra file input start /-->
            <span class="btn fileinput-button">
                <span>Other...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files2[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <!--/ Extra file input stop -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn primary start">Start upload</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn info cancel">Cancel upload</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn danger delete">Delete selected</button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span16">
            <table class="zebra-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have tried to work with the standard implementation of the js:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Does anyone have a complete working example? I simply need to upload groups of files to a php uploader.

Comment: Can you define specific problem ?

Comment: first i don't know what js i have to associate to this kind of form for this plugin... The example is partial and with the js in basic.html example it doesn't works

Comment: You have a ID define as fileupload, but in JAVASCRIPT you are using class .fileupload

Comment: i'm sorry ...my error ,i have corrected it but it was only a copy and paste error. It don't works anyway